# How to update only selected component with react hooks

Tags: react-hooks

I'm coding a to-do list using React hooks.
Every added item has two dropdown list where the user can decide how urgent the task (urgency value) is and how long the thing to do will take (speed value).
Updating either list will add their value into a 'score' property.

By clicking a "Sort" button I can sort the entries based on the score.

Right now the problem is that if I have more then one to-do item with different urgency and speed value, the score will always be the same for both components.

Can somebody help? Thanks

```
function ToDo(){
  const [ input, setInput ] = React.useState('')
  const [ toDo, setToDo ] = React.useState([])
  const [ score, setScore ] = React.useState(0)
  const [ speed, setSpeed ] = React.useState(0)
  const [ urgency, setUrgency ] = React.useState(0)

  return(
    <div>
      <h2>List of things to do</h2>
      <input
          value={ input }
          onChange={ (e) => setInput( e.target.value ) }/>
      <button 
        onClick={ () => {
          setToDo( toDo.concat(input))
          setInput('')
          }}>Add
      </button>
      <ul>
        { toDo.map(( task, idTask ) => {
          return (
            <li 
              key={idTask}
              score={ speed + urgency }>
              {task}<br/>
              <select onChange={(e) => { setSpeed(Number(e.target.value)) }}>
                <option value={1}>slow</option>
                <option value={2}>medium</option>
                <option value={3}>fast</option>
              </select><br/>
              <select onChange={(e) => { setUrgency(Number(e.target.value)) }}>
                <option value={1}>non-urgent</option>
                <option value={3}>urgent</option>
              </select>
              <span 
                onClick={ 
                  (index) => {
                    const newTodos = [...toDo]
                    newTodos.splice(index, 1);
                    setToDo( newTodos)
                  }}>
                [-------]
              </span>
            </li>
            )
          })
         }
      </ul>
      <button onClick={ 
          () => { 
            const sortMe = [...toDo].sort((a, b) => b - a)
            setToDo( sortMe )
          }}>Sort!</button>
    </div>
    )
  }

ReactDOM.render(<ToDo/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a different data model to achieve that. You should hold an array of objects for your `todos` (each `todo` will be an object) and each object should have an `urgency` property so you can set that individually.

Something like this:

```js
function App() {

  const [todos,setTodos] = React.useState([
    { id: 'todo1', text: 'This is todo1', urgency: 0 },
    { id: 'todo2', text: 'This is todo2', urgency: 1 }
  ]);
  
  function handleClick(id) {
    setTodos((prevState) => {
      let aux = Array.from(prevState);
      aux = aux.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.urgency === 0 ? todo.urgency = 1 : todo.urgency = 0;
        }
        return todo;
      });
      return aux;
    });
  }
  
  const todoItems = todos.map((todo) => 
    <li 
      key={todo.id}
      className={todo.urgency === 1 ? 'urgent' : 'normal'}
      onClick={()=>handleClick(todo.id)}
    >
      {todo.text}
      {!!todo.urgency && '<--- This is urgent'}
    </li>
  );

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        Click on the todos!
      </div>
      <ul>
        {todoItems}
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.urgent {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm trying to achieving something else. I edited my question and code...